# How to Capture paypal_fee in Paypal Smart Button/JS SDK (Laravel 8)

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, paypal

I want to retrieve the paypal_fee when paying an order using PayPal smart buttons/ Javascript SDK .

PayPal Smart Payment Button

[image: 1]

This is to compute the order net income before saving it in my database. I want to know how to retrieve the value of paypal_fee in every order and store it in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

The JS SDK actions.order.create / actions.order.capture are for very simple use cases. If you are going to do anything automated with the order information after capture, including saving it to a database, create and capture the order from a server.

Use the v2/checkout/orders API and make two routes (url paths) on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order'. You could use one of the (recently deprecated) Checkout-*-SDKs for the routes' API calls to PayPal, or your own HTTPS implementation of first getting an access token and then doing the call. Both of these routes should return/output **only** JSON data (no HTML or text). Inside the 2nd route, when the capture API is successful you should verify the amount was correct and store its resulting payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, which is the PayPal transaction ID) and perform any necessary business logic (such as reserving product or sending an email) immediately *before* forwarding return JSON to the frontend caller. In the event of an error forward the JSON details of it as well, since the frontend must handle such cases.

Pair those 2 routes with this frontend approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server .  (If you need to send any additional data from the client to the server, such as an items array or selected options, add a `body` parameter to the fetch with a value that is a JSON string or object)